# jqGrid inline navigator not initializing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I'm trying to initialize the inline navigator on my jqGrid. Using version 4.4.0. Code:

```
$('#line-items-grid').jqGrid({
    caption      : '',
    width        : 704,
    shrinkToFit  : 1,
    forceFit     : true,
    scrollOffset : 0,
    url          : '',
    datatype     : 'local',
    rowNum       : 20,
    viewrecords  : true,
    height       : 'auto',
    gridview     : true,
    autoencode   : true,
    pager        : '#line-items-pager',
    colModel     : [
        {label: 'Commodity',  name: 'contract_material', sortable: false, width: 99, cellattr: word_wrap, editable: true,  classes: 'line-item-contract-material', edittype: "select"},
        {label: 'Date',       name: 'date',              sortable: false, width: 77, cellattr: word_wrap, editable: true,  classes: 'line-item-date', editoptions: {
            dataInit: function (el) {
                $(el).datepicker();
            }
        }},
        {label: 'Vendor',     name: 'vendor',            sortable: false, width: 95, cellattr: word_wrap, editable: true,  classes: 'line-item-vendor', editoptions: {maxlength: "50"}},
        {label: 'Ticket/PO#', name: 'ticket_po_num',     sortable: false, width: 66, cellattr: word_wrap, editable: true,  classes: 'line-item-ticket-po-num', editoptions: {maxlength: "50"}},
        {label: 'Lbs',        name: 'lbs',               sortable: false, width: 73, cellattr: word_wrap, editable: true,  classes: 'line-item-lbs'},
        {label: 'Units',      name: 'units',             sortable: false, width: 49, cellattr: word_wrap, editable: true,  classes: 'line-item-units'},
        {label: 'Rate/Ton',   name: 'rate_per_ton',      sortable: false, width: 64, cellattr: word_wrap, editable: true,  classes: 'line-item-rate-per-ton'},
        {label: 'Rate/Unit',  name: 'rate_per_unit',     sortable: false, width: 64, cellattr: word_wrap, editable: true,  classes: 'line-item-rate-per-unit'},
        {label: 'Total',      name: 'total',             sortable: false, width: 72, cellattr: word_wrap, editable: true, classes: 'line-item-total'}
    ],
    jsonReader   : {
        repeatitems: false
    },
    onSelectRow  : function (id) {
        if (id && id !== lastsel) {
            $('#line-items-grid').jqGrid('restoreRow', lastsel);
            $('#line-items-grid').jqGrid('editRow', id,
                {
                    keys: true,
                    extraparam: {
                        reporting_period_id: function () { return $('#reporting_period_filter').val(); },
                        pickup_id: function () { return $('#pickup_filter').val(); },
                        lbs_per_ton: function () { return material_lbs_per_ton[$('#line-items-grid tr#' + id).find('td.line-item-contract-material select').val()]; }
                    },
                    oneditfunc: lineItemEditPrep,
                    aftersavefunc: lineItemSuccess,
                    errorfunc: lineItemError,
                    afterrestorefunc: function () { $('.qtip').qtip('destroy'); },
                    restoreAfterError: false
                });
            //clear out error messages
            $('.qtip').qtip('destroy');

            lastsel = id;
        }
    },
    gridComplete : lineItemViewPrep,
    editurl      : "line_items/line_item_edit"
});
$('#line-items-grid').jqGrid('navGrid', '#line-items-pager', {
    add: false,
    edit: false,
    del: false
});
$('#line-items-grid').jqGrid('inlineNav', '#line-items-pager');
```

I get the buttons for the regular navigator (view and refresh) showing up, but no buttons for the inline navigator. What am I missing?

(Side note, if it's relevant: I'm setting the url and datatype options on a separate function that loads data into the grid.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to use the last version of jqGrid. It's currently version 4.4.5. Between jqGrid 4.4.0 and 4.4.5 **many** bugs were fixed.

The problem which you describe was fixed already in jqGrid 4.4.1. If you really require to use old 4.4.0 then you should fix [the line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.0/js/grid.formedit.js#L1994) inside of `navButtonAdd` method (it has line number 8796 in `jquery.jqGrid.src.js`)

```js
if( p.id && $("#"+$.jgrid.jqID(p.id), findnav).html() !== null )  {return;}
```

to the line

```js
if( p.id && $("#"+$.jgrid.jqID(p.id), findnav)[0] !== undefined )  {return;}
```

Compare the result of [your original demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/shroud0.htm) with [the same code which used the described above fix](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/shroud.htm).